# Why is my UILabel not updating as the datepicker changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import "DatePickerViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface DatePickerViewController ()


@end

@implementation DatePickerViewController

@synthesize dateLabel;
@synthesize pick;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIBarButtonItem *saveDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(saveList:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveDate;
    pick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [pick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,120)];
    [pick addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


}

-(void)saveList:(id)sender {
    // need to finish

}

-(IBAction)updateDateLabel {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date]];

}
```

Comment: Verify that `dateLabel` is not `nil`.

Comment: Side note - This line: `dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date]];` should be: `dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date];`.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show you adding the picker to the view. Was this left out of the posted code or do you not actually add the picker to the view?

Comment: @rdelmar no it doesn't crash

Comment: @rmaddy i put it in the view in storyboard. it's linked up to pick. pick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [pick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,120)];
    [pick addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

Comment: @STANGMMX you do understand that the point of IBOutlets is to obviate the need for initialization code, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your registration for events from the picker is using a selector that expects one argument (`@selector(updateDateLabel:)` expects a method of the form `-updateDateLabel:(id)arg`), whereas what you have implemented takes no arguments (`-updateDateLabel`)

Of course, all of this is moot considering that you've reassigned your picker from the one that was de-archived from the storyboard.  Remove the initialization code and hook up the IBAction to the picker in the storyboard.

Comment: So how exactly could this work if you don't a) add the picker to your view. b) show us some outlet declarations?

Comment: Ahhhh. I had implemented this previously using a UITextField, and did uitextfield.delegate = self; uitextfield.inputView = pick; so i never had to hook anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Change `-(IBAction)updateDateLabel {` to `-(IBAction)updateDateLabel:(id)sender {`