# Why is this NSDate the current date and not the date chosen from the picker?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The goal is to have the user set a due date and save this due date into an object.

Here is the object's saveListItem method:

```
+ (void)saveListItem:(PFUser *)theUser withName:(NSString *)theListItem withDate:(NSDate *)theDueDate
{
    PFObject *listObject = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"ListItem"];
    [listObject setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"author"];
    [listObject setObject:theListItem forKey:@"listName"];
    [listObject setObject:theDueDate forKey:@"dueDate"];
    [listObject save];
    NSLog(@"%@", listObject);

}
```

Here is where it is called:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *saveDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(saveList:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveDate;
    pick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [pick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,120)];
    [pick addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(IBAction)saveList:(id)sender {

    [ListItemObject saveListItem:[PFUser currentUser] withName:listFieldText withDate:pick.date];
}

-(IBAction)updateDateLabel:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:pick.date];
}
```

I checked the referencing outlet for the date picker and it is set to pick.

The object that is being saved is the current date, and not the date chosen on the picker.

Comment: is updateDateLabel triggered once ? did u changed ur picker date ?

Comment: pick.date will be todays date.. please log it...

Comment: @Ramshad I added the code for updatedatelabel, but I didn't think that would affect it. it's only changing a label. if the user changes the picker date, wouldn't it change pick.date?

Comment: @Ramshad Ah yeah you're right. pick isn't the date that I pick from Date picker. Hmm. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: This is the same problem as your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454665/why-is-my-uilabel-not-updating-as-the-datepicker-changes. You are creating a wasted `UIDatePicker` in the code instead of using the one you added in IB.

Comment: @rmaddy ahhh. thanks again. I'll comment my code so it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code not doing any thing wrong.

However , here is the worst case of fix,

```
-(void)updateDateLabel:(id)sender {

   formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
   [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
   dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:((UIDatePicker *)sender).date];
}       

-(IBAction)saveList:(id)sender {

    NSDate *selectedDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateLabel.text];
    [ListItemObject saveListItem:[PFUser currentUser] withName:listFieldText withDate:selectedDate];
}
```